# Как написать ножницы на C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Ищу конкретную статью либо видеоурок, может быть кто то уже видел и я теряю время в поисках?

Я про ножницы из win7. Просто программа, полностью повторяющая функционал. Хочу разобраться.

Comment: Что за ножницы?

Comment: Ножницы - приложение в windows7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так проще самому написать. Там функционала-то почти нет:

1. Получаешь DC рабочего стола.
2. Помещаешь картинку на созданную форму без заголовка, растянутую на всю рабочую область (хотя ножницы возможно действуют по-другому)
3. Реализуешь выбор области (на мауз даун событие, мауз мув и мауз ап). По мауз ап, берешь выбранную область и помещаешь ее в виде картинки в буфер обмена.

Comment: Первые 2 пункта я уже реализовал, вот с третьим проблемка. Да и у ножниц функционал несколько побольше, там есть возможность выбирать произвольную область и окно, хотя мне хватит и прямоугольника. С другой стороны все же хочется понять как это сделано. Так же не особо понимаю как сделать 2 окна. (там где рабочий стол и второе как в ножницах).

Comment: Ну 3-й пункт, собственно, основной.

По MouseDown получаешь координаты начала отсчета. По MouseMove запоминаешь траекторию движения (если тебе нужно получить произвольное выделение области или просто отрисовываешь область прямоугольником, чтобы было видно, что ты  собираешь скопировать). По MouseUp получаешь вторую координату для прямоугольника (или замыкаешь область для произвольного выделения области). 

После того, как мы определили, то что мы будем копировать (например левый верхний угол и правый нижний для прямоугольника, мы копируем этот фрагмент картинки в буфер обмена.

Comment: Собственно копирование данных с картинки придется реализовать самостоятельно (я не знаю, есть ли готовый функционал копирование областей...) можно пробежаться по картинке, получить перечень пикселей попадающих в выбранную область и поместить их в новую картинку.

Работа с изображениями производится через Bitmap и Image, как я думаю ты уже понял. Работа с буфером обмена - Clipboard. Вполне хорошо работа с ними описана в хелпе.

Comment: а в чем проблема в двух окнах? Form frm1 = new Form(); Form frm2 = new Form(); frm1.Show(); frm2.Show();

вот тебе и два окна... Помести их оба поверх всех окон. при нажатии на одно из окон, второе скрывается, как я понял в ножницах =)

Comment: Я так понимаю нужен второй PictureBox для выделения? Чтобы рисовать произвольное выделение и прямоугольник?

Comment: Зачем тебе визуальный компонент?.. достаточно использовать Image img = new Image; Или Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap();